# From contact form to paypal

Tags: forms, paypal

here's my problem. I'm hosting my website on wordpress.com so I really don't have much flexibility to adjust and switch up codes till i upgrade to premium which i'm not too sure i might do because it costs alot. But i really hope to get a possible answer to this.

I created a form on my site for people to register for an upcoming event and a paypal button to for them to pay. Only problem is not everyone that registers pays. and i kinda want it to be mandatory (required) for people to pay before submitting the form or if there's a way to redirect them to paypal through the submit button.

Like i said i hope to get a possible answer to this but if not please feel free to suggest any other means you think can help me out. I'll be most grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best coding wise answers, but for quick solutions that I've done and are common:

1. Put the registration page as a thank you from PayPal, which is a
   setting when doing a PayPal payment button.
2. Put the link to payment in the registration email that's sent to them, from there they have to pay to become verified.
3. Use a premade plugin (probably your best bet here) like S2Member (which I would recommend), there's a lot of free options though. This would handle what I was saying above out of box. This would be the quickest/fastest solution.